# How to add celery settings to django?

Tags: python, django, celery

I would like to add the following celery setting modification to the django app

```
worker_send_task_event = False
task_ignore_result = True
task_acks_late = True 
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 10
```

In my celery.py, I got

```
import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'server.settings')

app = Celery('server')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

And my `tasks.py`

```
@shared_task
def some_task():
    pass
```

Celery is executed using the following

```
command: celery -A server worker -Ofair — without-gossip — without-mingle — without-heartbeat
```

I have added them directly to the Django `settings.py` but I am not sure if Celery actually picked those settings up. So I am wondering if there is another way to add them or someone has a similar experience?

I am using

```
celery==5.2.1
Django==3.2.5
```

Comment: You will find settings in here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings

Comment: my question is not about the settings, my question is about where do you put in the Django project folder

Comment: Put them in your  project  `settings.py`. for example `worker_send_task_events` will be `CELERY_SEND_EVENTS=False`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use upper case naming like described [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/history/whatsnew-4.0.html?highlight=CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER#lowercase-setting-names)

Example:
Use `CELERYD_SEND_EVENTS = True` istead of `worker_send_task_event = False`